# can't run ng serve in development mode

Tags: javascript, angular, serve, angular12

I can't run `ng serve`in development mode.

I've upgraded Angular v11 to v12. Since then, I have compiling delays and development mode appears to not be enabled.

I'm always getting this warning:

```
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
```

My Lazy Chunk files are like this:

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSdT4.png)

and is taking a lot of time to debug anything since the compile files are being set on the browser.

[Browser Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgfdp.png)

I've already check my enviroment.ts variables and are set to:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
};
```

My Angular Extension for Chrome is warning me that I'm running in production, even when I don't want to:

```
We detected an application built with production configuration. Angular DevTools only supports development builds.
```

ng serve section on angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "backoffice:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "backoffice:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
```

Exactly like the one on v11, i've checked

Update:
Migrating Issues.
Runned
`ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.0`
like @BojanKojog answer bellow.

Comment: Show your angular.json file. Specifically "serve" section.

Comment: Did you have any issues updating? Try running update migrations again `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.0`.

Comment: I didn't think i've had issues! But that command solved the problem!
You made my day!

Comment: I'll post it as answer for others to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rerun update migrations

```sh
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.0
```

[Explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42100#issuecomment-847331725)

> Projects that have not used ng update to update to v12 are missing important migrations that switch some builder options to their default values in v11. Without this migration, the builder now assumes production configuration as the defaults were changed to represent production builds by default. An automatic migration that is run in ng update @angular/cli would set the affected options to their prior defaults, such that a project continues to behave the same. Without this migration however, builds are configured for production with the corresponding optimisations turned on, making development builds very slow.
>
> Please use ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.0 to apply the migrations or update using ng update @angular/core @angular/cli when still on v11.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as the OP and had already tried this solution before finding this post without any luck.  Any other ideas?